# facebook button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to use facebook share button but it is not showing the button i have check that code in chrome, firefox but its not working.
it shows me that error

[image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=1082021301831859";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

 <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://fiercemarriage.com/encouraging-marriage-quotes-images" data-layout="icon"></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: did you add your website/link to the fb application?

Comment: which application i dont know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FB like button only works on the domain added in your FB app.. That means if you are sitting in a dev/staging environment, it doesn't work.

Comment: how to do that i have watch many tutorial but no one tell me that and how to do that

Comment: You probably doesn't need a FB app, but the site url in the FB script should match the current domain, otherwise it wont work

Comment: then what is the solution

Comment: sir i am creating post and i need that button on every post then every time i will do that process